# Matplotlib: X-axis tick mark spacing is not centered with all columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot 3 different distributions on one histogram. For reasons I don't understand, the columns are centered between the X-axis tick marks for low values, but not for high values. Confusingly, when I try random numbers instead of my data, the issue is resolved.

Plotting function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('font',family='Phetsarath OT')
plt.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 12
%matplotlib inline

def plotHistogram_test(x, y, z):

    plt.figure(figsize=[10, 6])
    plt.hist([x, y, z], color=['blue','black', 'red'], bins=10, align='mid', rwidth=0.5)

    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none')
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('none')

    plt.title('', fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel('', fontsize=14, labelpad=5)
    plt.ylabel('', fontsize=14, labelpad=5)


    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1), fontsize=12)    
    plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', left=True, bottom=True,labelbottom=True) 

    plt.show()
```

Output with random numbers:

```
plotHistogram_test(np.random.uniform(size=100), np.random.uniform(size=100), np.random.uniform(size=100))
```

[image]

Output with real data:

[image]

**Notice how the columns begin centered, then slowly drift off...**

Comment: that's because matplotlib see these labels as numbers, the distance between the numbers should be fixed, try to make categorical value for `xticks`

Comment: Do you mind clarifying with an example?

Comment: You specify `bins=10`; but apparently you don't want any 10 bins, but some very specific ones, namely `[0,0.1,0.2, ....1]`

Comment: you want each bar to be placed on one number exactly?

Comment: Ernest provided solution. `bins=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `bins=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]` resolves the issue.